# htaccess to remove print.html from url

Tags: .htaccess

We are currently hosting a large joomla site.
Google has indexed hundreds of the "print" versions of our pages.

for example if we have an article with the url:
www.mysite.com/funnyarticle.html

the joomla site automatically created:
www.mysite.com/funnyarticle/print.html

We have moved the site and deleted these pages, so they now get a 404 error from google.
We would like to redirect or rewrite (not sure what is the correct terminology) the "print" urls to their respective articles.

I would like to use htaccess to remove:
/print.html

and replace it with:
.html

I have seen examples but cannot get them to work correctly.
So I was hoping I could get specific advise on how to remove and replace the exact code above.

Thanks for your time.

Regards,

Aforantman

Answer (score 1):

You can create a robot.txt file with following lines.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*/print.html
```

this will disallow search engine robots to access files with name print.html.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a `RewriteRule`. See Apache's guide on how to use them: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html

But if you just want Google (and other search engines) to ignore those print versions, put a corresponding entry in you `robots.txt`. That way you don't need to fiddle around with Joomla's way of generating and accessing the print version for your human visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put these lines in your `DOCROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteRule   ^(.*?)/print.html $1.html [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect any Google user clicking through to one of these pages to the correct article.  If your article names can contain / then remove the `?` from the above; the rule will still work but might take a few more μS runtime :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use robots.txt as said by Jishnu.This is the best way to do this.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*/print.html
```

Comment: This doesn't supply any additional information to Jishnu's answer, if you support an answer, add a comment to it. If you don't have the rep to comment then go earn it.